# Can I renegotiate my salary as the offer letter signed was 4 months back

Tags: salary, job-offer, ethics, negotiation, contractors

I have been working as a contractor in a company in the US from last 1.6 years. Around 6 months back, they offered me a full-time role. I gladly agreed as I like the company and wanted to continue working here. It took 2 months to finalize on the interview process and other paperwork such as background checks.

The package they offered was almost the same that I am making in the contractor role, but I signed it thinking about other additional benefits like PTO and health insurance. They agreed to give me a joining bonus of $6000. Unfortunately, due to some internal management and HR issue, my joining got delayed.

It has been more than 4 months since I signed my offer letter and I haven't got the joining date yet. They say they are trying to push my joining and assure that I will get it soon, but nothing has been finalized yet. I was planning to ask for a raise after completing 1 year with my contracting company, but since the client offered FT, I didn't pursue it. It has been 1.6 years going on as a contractor on the same pay.

Should I ask for re-negotiation or at least an increase in the joining bonus, in case they finally sort out the issue and ask me to join or should I join at the same pay? How long should I wait to see if the FTE is finally coming in or keep going like this? What are my options? I like the company and do not want to leave it. Just that the delay has made me stuck as a contractor not asking for pay raise from my employer in the hopes of getting a FT soon.

Comment: What do you mean by "signed my offer letter"?  Do you have a written agreement?

Comment: Yes, I signed and submitted the offer letter.  The client said I will be given a joining date only after I sign the letter. I was about to join 2 weeks later as per their anticipated joining date  They had informed my employer too about my FTE hiring and they gave their go ahead. So, I am still in a limbo thinking should I ask for a raise from my employer now or be patient and wait for the full time ( trusting my manager's assurance) and renegotiate it later or accept the pay what I signed 4 months back.

Comment: They are way too slow and the whole thing is a shambles.  "It has been 1.6 years on the same pay" == career suicide.  Walk away and start fresh and a fast-paced aggressive company.

Comment: @Fattie Yes right. Too slow. I was quite surprised when the overall interview process took 2 months given that I was working on the team. The internal conflict was expected to resolve by Oct end and now its 10 days past Jan and I am still floating in the middle.  My manager also adds that any way we are not going to get rid of you, So till the time it's not resolved we will keep extending your contract. This made me think that they are now happy to make me continue as a contractor than hire FT.

Comment: As a fellow Worker, I would just urge you to get a dramatic raise, and fast!  Good luck!!!!

Answer (score 1):

> I was planning to ask for a raise after completing 1 year with my contracting company

There is no reason not to go ahead with this. Even if you got the Full Time the next day, they're two separate issues.

At the moment your offer is vague and hasn't eventuated. When it does you may want to renegotiate and or see what other benefits there are to joining, but meanwhile there is no reason not to ask for a raise with your current company. A raise would put you in a much stronger negotiating position with the full time position.

Also the 4 months was not your fault in any way, so you may be in a comfortable enough position to ask tell them your circumstances have changed and you would now need more to move to them. By the time they do offer the full time they will have made more of an investment already which makes your position stronger. AT the moment all they've invested in is a few emails, and they may well have found they cannot actually hire you anyway and are just putting you off. Many contracting companies contractually prohibit clients from head hunting their staff.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I joined the contracting company, I had asked them about the process of raise and how does it work. They said that they will reach out to my manager (client)  for any pay raise I ask and see if he approves of it. Since my manager is the one pushing for my full time, I felt I would come across as a greedy person asking money when he is trying to hire me, but given that it is now 4 months, I felt I should initiate the talk with my employer. So, wanted to know what's the best way to approach.

Comment: Initiate it as if the job offer etc,. doesn't exist, they're two totally separate things

Answer (score -1):

Here's your choices:

- **What happens if you attempt to renegotiate and they say no?** Possibly nothing. In which case, it didn't hurt to ask. Or they may be pissed off that you're trying to change the deal with "everything was agreed upon" and you might lose the whole gig.
- **What happens if you attempt to renegotiate and they say yes?** You get more money. You're in a better position to judge which of those is most likely.

Comment: This isn't an answer. Just a breakdown of the situation which OP already knows. Downvoted.